# Download progress bar freezing up when downloading Jar files

Tags: java, javascript, html

I am trying to create a download progress bar that shows the progress of the download of a Jar file.  I have 1 jar file that loads multiple others, so from within the main Jar file, I have callbacks that call back to the javascript of the HTML. I want to use these callbacks to update a html progress bar through javascript.

This is what I have so far:

When the javascript receives a callback from java, I print it to the console, and also change the text of the loading bar.

```
window.LoadingState = function (status,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)   
{
   console.log("LoadingState");
   console.log(status,a,b,c,d,e,f,g);
   LOADBAR.innerHTML=status;
}
```

The status prints fine in the browser console, but the loading bar text is only updated after the Jar file has been downloaded (It only shows 100% and nothing in between) In other words, **It freezes completely until the workload is done.**

I call back to Js using the following line of code at multiple places within my Java:

window.call("LoadingState", new Object[]{50,"Updater"});

And this is what the console receives:

[image: Console]

However, nothing happens on the progress bar until the loading is completely done. Is there a way to get around this freeze?

Comment: I think that you don't work with your file asynchronously. How do you call first jar file?

Comment: I do not understand your description well.  But from the little I can tell, if it is a *desktop app.,* the answer is either [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) or [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html) or a combination of the two.